# Controlling a KVM guest Linux OS using Java without network access

Tags: java, controls, kvm

I know there is

```
kvm -stdio
```

to access a kvm guest without having to set up networking. But it is slow and probably cumbersome. Are there better solutions? I want to run commands and transfer data.

Main problem is that I don't want to run anything with root privileges and I don't want a local bridge network requirement for ssh access because that requires a specific host configuration that cannot be done by the user ad-hoc. Maybe there are alternatives? User-networking etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Networking:

```
kvm -hda img -device e1000,netdev=user.0 \
    -netdev user,id=user.0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22 -nographic
```

User networking with port forward. User can listen on ports > 1024, and kvm redirects it to port 22. Should work with everything tcp (ssh, scp, rsync, telnet etc.).